# How to configure uwsgi to use multiple python paths

Tags: python, wsgi, uwsgi

Is it possible to configure uwsgi to use multiple python paths?

I have defined a python path in my uwsgi.ini file, but I need to also use a code from a second python project. My current python path configuration:

```
pythonpath = /Users/vingtoft/Documents/Development/archii/server/archii2/app/
```

Comment: Have you tried to use a colon as a separator? e.g. `pythonpath = /path/1/:/path/2/`

Comment: That does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: 1. Try to specify `pythonpath` twice in uwsgi.ini; 2. Try to pass `--pythonpath` twice to `uwsgi` command; 3. Add extra paths to `sys.path` somewhere in your code.

Comment: Solution 1 solved my problem, thank you. Please write it in an answer, then I'm able to give you 25 points.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are seem to be at least 4 ways to achieve that:

1. specify `pythonpath` twice in uwsgi.ini;
2. pass `--pythonpath` argument to uwsgi command twice;
3. set `PYTHONPATH` environment variable with paths concatenated with a colon;
4. add extra paths to `sys.path` somewhere in your code.